# How to split HDMI signal to two displays (not at the same time)

Tags: display, hdmi, tv, signal

I would like to run my PC on my monitor (for work) or sometimes on my TV (for gaming), not both at the same time. What kind of adaptor am I looking for?

I've tried searching but was unable to find something which will do the job.

Comment: *"How to split HDMI signal ..."* -- In your situation, you do not want to *"split"* the signal, but rather *switch* it to another display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option is to buy an "HDMI Switch." This will be a small box with 1 HDMI port on one side and 2 or more on the opposite side, and usually a button on the device that lets you switch outputs. Run your computer to the input side, and run your work monitor and gaming monitor to your preferred outputs. Then it just takes a click of a button to switch between output monitors. You can find these easy by searching "HDMI Switch 2 to 1" on Amazon. [Here's the one I use on my desk at home, not the cheapest option but I like the look of it with my other hardware.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B079JQ9XXV) Don't forget, you will probably need to buy an extra HDMI cable to complete this set up if you don't already have at least 3 to use! Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: What a brilliant answer, thank you. Not enough rep to upvote yet but I have accepted this as the answer.